# Having trouble with writing a piece of code to return the maximum value of a list, using this specific structure

Tags: python, max

I am struggling with what is probably a rather easy fault, but here it is regardless: the question asks for a piece of code using the following structure to return the maximum value of a list. I apologise if it is something really simple, but I am very new to this

Using the `max()` function is not allowed

```
def lmax(lst):
    i=0
    val=0
    while i < len(lst):
        a=lst[i]
        if a>val:
            lst[i]=val
        i=i+1
    return val
```

Simply returns 0, regardless of the list input

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201477/discussion-on-question-by-rookiecoder2345-having-trouble-with-writing-a-piece-of) as requested.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you were setting the value in the list to the current largest `lst[i]=val` when in reality you wanted to keep it. I've also reduced the use of by using a `for` loop rather than a `while`.

```
def lmax(lst):
    largest = lst[0]
    for current in lst:
        if current>largest:
            largest = current
    return largest
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code is that you set

```
lst[i]=val
```

instead of setting

```
val = lst[i]
```

It would be simpler in a for-loop, though.

```
def lmax(lst):
    val=0
    for i in lst:
        if i > val:
            val = i
    return val
```

Also, note that your function will not work if all of your values are negative numbers. In that case, val needs to be set the first element in the list. and check each consecutive 'i' against that.

This is what your variable assignment would look like:

```
val= lst[0]
```